# careers: linking projects on launchpad

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

Careers currently allows to link projects on github, sourceforce, bitbucket, but not launchpad.

Is it possible to have this feature ?

Adding more text because apparently I don't meet the "quality standards". Additional request is therefore to clarify what these quality standards are ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launchpad is working to develop an API that suits our purposes. When they offer this, we'll include Launchpad on Careers 2.0.

Update: nothing came of the API but we added "other" as a type of open-source project, where you can paste in an arbitrary URL and we do our best to make sense of it. You might try this example: https://launchpad.net/drizzle

Comment: Awwww... that's definitely a disappointment. Doesn't Launchpad's existing API provide the functionality you need?